# How can I display the contents of a variable that uses .sum() in a label using tkinter

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, data-cleaning

I'm creating a counter to count how many empty cells there are when a user uploads a CSV file. I am also using treeview to display the contents of the CSV. The `print("There are", emptyCells.sum(), "empty cells")` works and prints the number to the console but I want to display this in a label so the user can view this in the GUI. It is not displaying anything but a `"row"` is being added to the application after a file has been uploaded where the label should be as everything moves down but no contents are being inserted into the label.

```py
emptyCells = (df[df.columns] == " ").sum()

# print("There are", emptyCells.sum(), "empty cells")

tree.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=50)
messagebox.showinfo("Success", "File Uploaded Successfully")

stringVariable = StringVar()
printVariable = ("There are", emptyCells.sum(), "empty cells")
#print(printVariable)

stringVariable.set(printVariable)
lbl = Label(windowFrame, textvariable=stringVariable, font=25)
lbl.pack()
```

Comment: By what `event` do you want to update the `Label`? It will not work unless there is no `event` which you ask for to happen in order to change the `Label`

Comment: After adding dummy dataframe `df`, your code works fine.

Comment: @grumpyp I’m wanting it to appear after an “open” button is pressed to open a CSV file that the user can select. The number of empty cells should then print in a new label after a “successfully uploaded” message is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question you want to update your tkinter `label` by a button click.  You would do this with something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk(className="button_click_label")
root.geometry("200x200")

messagebox.showinfo("Success","Test")
emptyCells = (df[df.columns] == " ").sum()
l1 = Label(root, text="Emptycells?")

def clickevent():
    txt = "there are", emptyCells
    l1.config(text=txt)


b1 = Button(root, text="clickhere", command=clickevent).pack()

l1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It is not tested with the `pandas` library but should work for you!

Comment: I think I needed the config to get it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the sum you need already in the `emptyCells` variable? Why do you need to use the .sum() function again in the print statement?

```
printVariable = f"There are {emptyCells} empty cells"
```

Comment: Because if i dont it prints what column the empty cells are in and not the total number, so it says ID = 1, Name = 1, Country = 2, Colour = 0 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the tkinter label is not happening when I try to reproduce the problem, the label shows.  The cause must be somewhere else in the code.

I've not got pandas installed so I've summed a list instead.  This shows a GUI with two labels when I run it.

```
import tkinter as tk

emptyCells = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]  # keep it simple.

windowFrame = tk.Tk()

old = tk.StringVar()
stringVariable = tk.StringVar()

old_print = ("There are", sum(emptyCells), "empty cells") # Returns a tuple
printVariable = "There are {} empty cells".format( sum(emptyCells) ) # Returns a string.

old.set( old_print )
stringVariable.set(printVariable)

lbl_old = tk.Label( windowFrame, textvariable = old )
lbl_old.pack()

lbl = tk.Label(windowFrame, textvariable=stringVariable, font=25)
lbl.pack()

windowFrame.mainloop()
```

Does this work when you run it?  Does it help identify where the problem is in the code which doesn't show the labels?

Comment: I have to do it the way I did to get the number of empty cells in a CSV that can change any time so it can’t be hard coded and I want the label to appear after a button is pressed and not straight away.